# Apache remove www from https using virtual hosts

Tags: apache, http, https

Is there a way to force removal of www from the domain name that is https enabled via the .conf file?

Currently I force https, which covers most things via:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works — I can go to

> www.example.com

and it will redirect me to

> https://example.com

However, if I add back in the www. it will error as my certificate doesn't cover www. I know it's highly unlikely someone would add in the https://www. I would still like a method to cover this off. Is it even possible without using a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect https://www.example.com to anything ( like https://example.com ) if you don't have a certificate for www.example.com

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your answer. So as I understand it I will just need to apply a cert to both www. and none www in that case

Comment: Correct, but you must add a redirect too. See the other response for that.

Comment: I don't see another response.